# Could not create task of type 'ShadowJar'

Tags: gradle

I have this error:
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHjUi.png)

I checked my Eclipse preferences/Gradle, and the the Gradle directory is well set. 
Besides, I have this stack error in my console when I try to refresh my project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\java\admin\build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':admin'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.ShadowJavaPlugin']
   > Could not create task of type 'ShadowJar'.
```

Do you have any idea of what's happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's kind of hard to guess...

Comment: Which part do you need to see exactly?

Comment: In Java Build Path, the Gradle dependencies library is uninitialized, instead of persisted...

Comment: What is your gradle version?

Comment: Can you show the part of your build.gradle where you're adding the Shadow plugin?

Comment: `apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'`

Comment: `buildscript{dependencies{}}` as well please, coz this is where you define the version of the plugin. Add the details to your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gradle 2.11 breaks compatibility with shadowjar version 1.2.2. You can fix this by updating to shadowjar version 1.2.3.

Source: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/commit/918a649b608f34dc0902d8d7aba21326ae5dfe8d

Comment: Worked for me:)